# Updating two tables in a single Query

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
      public void updateCustomerOnSubmit(String customerNumber, String customerEmail,   int pickupId, int statusId, int itemTypeId, int itemActionId, String itemSerial, String itemRemark){

    ContentValues c = updateCustomerInfoContentValues(customerNumber, customerEmail, statusId);
    String query = "UPDATE " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE 
            + " INNER JOIN " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE 
            + " ON " +   DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE 
            +" = " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_ACCODE
            + " SET " + DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_CONTACT + "='" + customerNumber
            + "' ," + DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_EMAIL +  "='" + customerEmail 
            + "' ," + DatabaseConstant.CUSTOMER_STATUS + " = " + statusId
            + " , " + DatabaseConstant.ITEM_TYPE_ID + " = " + itemTypeId 
            + " , " + DatabaseConstant.ITEM_ACTION_ID + " = " + itemActionId 
            + " , "+ DatabaseConstant.ITEM_SERIAL  + " ='" + itemSerial 
            + "' , " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUPITEM_REMARK + " ='" + itemRemark
            + "' , " + DatabaseConstant.ITEM_STATUS + " = " + statusId
            + " WHERE " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ITEM_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.PICKUPITEM_ID + " = " + pickupId 
            + " AND " + DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_CUSTOMER_DETAIL_TABLE+"."+DatabaseConstant.PICKUP_ID + " = " + pickupId;
    Log.i("query", query);
    database.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
```

My Question is that am I on a right way and other one is that its throwing a exception.
That is:

```
   06-18 01:40:47.178: E/SQLiteLog(1516): (1) near "'INNER JOIN'": syntax error
```

My Query formed in log is :

```
   UPDATE pickup_customer_detail 'INNER JOIN' pickup_item_detail ON pickup_customer_detail.customer_accode = pickup_item_detail.customer_accode SET customer_contact='9810530861' ,customer_email='vishal.nigam@computerware.co' ,status = 1 , item_type_id = 0 , item_action_id = 1 , item_serial ='5884626247' , pickupItem_remark ='thankß' , status = 1 WHERE pickup_item_detail.pickupItem_id = 3 AND pickup_customer_detail.pickup_id = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UPDATE statement can update only a single table.

To update values in two table, you must use two UPDATE statements.
(And use `execSQL`, not `rawQuery`.)